# PLS-00103 error when comping Oracle stored function

Tags: oracle, java-stored-procedures

Given the following Java which is loaded into the database using loadjava:

```
package grassie.example;

public class Example {

    public static String test(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And given the following Oracle Stored Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'grassie.example.Example.test() RETURN java.lang.String';
```

Why does the function not compile with the following error?:

`Error(3,1): PLS-00311: the declaration of "grassie.example.Example.test() RETURN java.lang.String" is incomplete or malformed`

Oracle client is 9.2.0.8.0, database is 9.2.0.8.0. Using SQL Developer 2.1.0.63

edit: Ammended my question based on answers below.

To further clarify, I created this simple test class and function because I am having problems with more complicated Java and stored functions, which accept and return various parameter types.

Comment: Don't have `Java` on my `XE` installation, but AFAIK, Java keywords should be lowercase. Try replacing `RETURN` with `return` in the `NAME` clause.

Comment: @Quassnoi please reply with a full answer so I give you credit for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the empty parentheses in the function declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'grassie.example.Example.test() RETURN java.lang.String';
```

**Update:**

`Java` keywords should be lowercase. Try replacing `RETURN` with `return` in the `NAME` clause.

Comment: I do that, I get the following error: `Error(3,1): PLS-00311: the declaration of "grassie.example.Example.test() RETURN java.lang.String" is incomplete or malformed`

Answer (score 1):

if the function has no parameters you don't need parentheses ():

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION() RETURN NUMBER AS
  2  BEGIN
  3     RETURN 0;
  4  END;
  5  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN NUMBER AS
  2  BEGIN
  3     RETURN 0;
  4  END;
  5  /

Function created
```

Answer (score 0):

Function definition should be like the below codes,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEMO_SCM.TEST_FUNCTION RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'grassie.example.Example.test() **return** java.lang.String';
```

Comment: it seems, the answer is already accepted and you are duplicated it